# Locating the mbid for various tracks with musicbrainzws2-java

Tags: java, musicbrainz

I have imported the musicbrainzws2-java library into my project and I have been reading through the documentation that MusicBrainz has on their web service. It is very confusing though. I was wondering if someone could help me understand how to navigate through the MusicBrainz data base. I don't understand the terminology and my main goal of using the database is to gather the mbid's for various songs.

Right now this is what I have.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArtistSearchFilterWs2 filter = new ArtistSearchFilterWs2();

    filter.setArtistName("Lindsey Stirling");
    filter.setLimit((long) 100);
    filter.setMinScore((long) 0);
    filter.setOffset((long) 0);

    ArtistSearchWs2 search = new ArtistSearchWs2(filter);

    List<ArtistResultWs2> result = search.getFullList();

    /*
    for(ArtistResultWs2 artist : result) {
        System.out.println(artist.getArtist().getName() + " " + i);
        i++;

        if(artist.getArtist().getName() == "Lindsey Stirling") {

            System.out.println(artist.getArtist().getName() + " " + i);
            break;
        }

    }
    */

    String artistName = result.get(0).getArtist().getName();
    System.out.println(artistName);

    List<ReleaseWs2> releases = result.get(0).getArtist().getReleaseList().getReleases();

    System.out.println(releases.size());

    for(ReleaseWs2 release : releases) {
        System.out.println(release.getTitle());

    }
```

For some reason it says that there are 0 releases for the artist Lindsey Stirling and on top of that I don't know how to search for a specific song based off of an artist and album

Comment: I think you have to fetch the ReleaseGroups from the artist first, then the Releases from the group. At least that is how the WS works. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21857175/1904815

Answer (score 1):

`releases` does not contain any elements because the search server does not return this information for artist searches. To clarify this a bit: The "normal" [web service](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2/) of MusicBrainz and the [search web service](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2/Search) use the same XML model in their output, which means that the `ArtistWs2` class can represent a result from either of them.

Other than the search web service, the normal one allows you to [request more information](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2/#Subqueries) about the entity you're retrieving information for (in this case, you want release information for an `artist`, so you have to include `releases` in the `inc` parameter).

You can view the XML that the search server returns for your search [here](http://search.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=lindsey%20stirling), a request to the normal web service that includes release information is [here](https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/53e40f93-f4af-4f8c-819c-7bbe4b6f0a1c?inc=releases).

The following code (minus the imports) will do what you want:

```
ArtistSearchFilterWs2 filter = new ArtistSearchFilterWs2();

filter.setArtistName("Lindsey Stirling");
filter.setLimit((long) 100);
filter.setMinScore((long) 0);
filter.setOffset((long) 0);

ArtistSearchWs2 search = new ArtistSearchWs2(filter);
List<ArtistResultWs2> result = search.getFullList();

String artistName = result.get(0).getArtist().getName();
System.out.println(artistName);

// This is the artist as returned by the search server.
ArtistWs2 artist = result.get(0).getArtist();

Artist controller = new Artist();
// This is where you tell the library that you want to have the artists
// releases included in the result.
controller.getIncludes().setReleases(true);

// This is the artist as returned by the MusicBrainz server, including the
// release information.
ArtistWs2 lindsey = controller.lookUp(artist);

List<ReleaseWs2> releases = lindsey.getReleaseList().getReleases();
System.out.println(releases.size());

for (ReleaseWs2 release : releases) {
    System.out.println(release.getTitle());
}
```

To understand how searches work, you should first read [the general documentation](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2/Search) and then find the search fields you need in the [recording search documentation](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2/Search#Recording). If you want to search (`recording` in MB-speak) for a song by a specific artist on a specific album, you need the `artist` and `releases` fields. For example, to search for "Mirror Haus" by "Lindsey Stirling" on "Shatter Me", you'd want to perform the following query: ["Mirror Haus" AND artist:"Lindsey Stirling" AND release:"Shatter Me"](http://search.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/?query=%22Mirror%20Haus%22%20AND%20release:%22Shatter%20Me%22%20AND%20artist:%22Lindsey%20Stirling%22).

The following code will do that:

```
    RecordingSearchFilterWs2 recfilter = new RecordingSearchFilterWs2();
    recfilter.setLimit((long) 100);
    recfilter.setMinScore((long) 0);
    recfilter.setOffset((long) 0);
    recfilter.setQuery("\"Mirror Haus\" AND release:\"Shatter Me\" AND artist:\"Lindsey Stirling\"");
    RecordingSearchWs2 recsearch = new RecordingSearchWs2(recfilter);
    List<RecordingResultWs2> recresult = recsearch.getFullList();
    System.out.println(recresult.size());
    System.out.println(recresult.get(0).getRecording().toString());
```